# POM.xml multiple errors – Maven dependency problems

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, pom.xml, maven-dependency

I am relatively new to Selenium and Maven. I cloned the project (project for the test automation). I got multiple issues with pom.xml.

[image]

[image]

There are 2 errors:

1st. error and the biggest one:  Missing artifact …

2nd. error: Failed to read artifact descriptor for…

Regarding the first one, I noticed that .jar files do present, but the error messages still indicated. i.e. the error is showing “Missing artifact io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.43.Final”, however corresponding .jar file is present in the folder, and it is found in Maven Dependencies section of the Project Explorer.

Same for the error message: “Missing artifact io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.43.Final” is indicated, and the file is present.

See below:

[image]

[image]

I tried to clean the project, I tried to update the project:

[image]

[image]

but with no success.

I read other articles here on Stack Overflow where similar problems have been described and discussed but with no success to solve my problem.

Regarding the second one: Failed to read artifact descriptor for… I did not manage to find anything.

Can you also recommend where I can Read about POM and how to set up Maven project in general and dependencies in particular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve.

I actually forgot to copy into .m2 folder file settings.xml

I copied it in:

[image]

Then I right clicked on the project and Maven - Update Project and I checked in Force Update of Snapshot/Releases But, at the same time I left Offline as unchecked.
Clicked OK and all my errors were gone, and I managed to run the automation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have tried the below, if you have not, worth trying.

Right click on the project --> Maven --> Update Project --> Select all the checkbox (including Offline and Force Update) as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  Yes, I tried this with no success, unfortunately.